# How to make lighter keyboard letter for iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uikeyboard

I don't understand why my app is getting "Bold Keyboard Letter" while other app like "Contact" is not?

I'm using UISearchbar and has configured as follow,

```
    keySearchBar = UISearchBar()
    keySearchBar!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    keySearchBar!.delegate = self
    keySearchBar!.placeholder = "Search"
    keySearchBar!.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    keySearchBar!.layer.borderWidth = 0
    keySearchBar!.keyboardAppearance = .light
```

What wrong with my setting and how?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you app does not support the correct resolution, are you sure you have all the correct launch screen setup?

Comment: As I manually setup the view without storyboard so, I'll try to add lunch screen and get back later, Thanks rckoenes for your advise.

Comment: Without launch screens (XIB, Storyboards or images) your app will not scale correctly. Thus the keyboard will look different.

Comment: Appreciate much for your help rckoenes.

Answer (score 0):

As I manually setup the view without storyboard so, adding "Lunch Screen" solved the problem.